# Why does my app not work on Android 2.3?

Tags: android, crash, gps, splash-screen, android-sdk-2.3

just a quick question about Android 2.3.

I've been receiving reports from people using my app that it crashes on startup in Android 2.3. It works absolutely fine on the other SDK versions as far as I can tell. Since I don't have a phone running Android 2.3 I can't test out where the error is, which makes it very frustrating to deal with!

Has anyone got any ideas what might have changed in Android 2.3 to mean the app crashes? Has anyone else had a similar problem?

The following are ideas I've had for what might be causing it...

1. Splash screen - on my main activity I trigger this in onCreate and it displays for 3 secs before finishing
2. I'm using the GPS capability of Android, has this vastly changed in 2.3 to mean that something's going wrong?
3. There's been a fundamental change in application startup in 2.3 that I'm not aware of.

Any feedback would be much appreciated!

** SOME MORE INFORMATION! **

With the help of someone running it on the Nexus S I've tracked down the problem to the following method:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("GPS functionality is required for this app. Would you like to      enable it?")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                   launchGpsOptions(); 
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
               }
           });
    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

Does anyone know why this suddenly won't work on Android 2.3 and/or how to fix it?

Many thanks!

Comment: Best bet is to find out exactly what is meant by "it crashes" then try to replicate that, checking logs and stepping through code. Otherwise its like finding a needle in sausage factory

Comment: Have you tried 2.3 in the emulator?

Comment: Are there any error in your logcat?

Comment: 2.2 and later should have Android Feedback, so when the crash happens the user can press the "Report" button in the crash dialog to send the stack crawl and other info to Market for you to see it.  If the people reporting this problem aren't able to do this, there is a good chance they are not running a regular build of Android so who knows what could be broken.

Comment: Thanks hackbod I'll ask users to make use of that functionality when they encounter an error.

Answer (score 1):

All my apps use this:

http://jyro.blogspot.com/2009/09/crash-report-for-android-app.html

Helps you track down bugs easily.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an unofficial build of Gingerbread, GPS is most likely broken. On all builds I have tried, the GPS does not work. When the app searches for GPS it can't find it, so it will crash. This exact behavior happens in the stock browser in 2.3 for the Moto Droid. Because it loads google.com and asks for location with GPS, it crashes. If this occurs on an official build(currently only Nexus S?), then ignore all of this.

Comment: No it was an official Nexus S version. Thanks for the heads-up on unofficial versions though.